# Strange difference between MongoDb on Windows and Macintosh

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm developing a node.js/mongodb app on Macintosh but I also like my code to work on Windows.

The following code works on the Mac but not on Windows:

```
var Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    Db = require('mongodb').Db;

var db = new Db('bookdb', new Server('localhost', 27017));

db.collection('books').insert({ author: 'bla' });
```

On Windows I have to add a call to db.open to make it work:

```
var Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    Db = require('mongodb').Db;

var db = new Db('bookdb', new Server('localhost', 27017));

db.open(function(err, db) {
    db.collection('books').insert({ author: 'bla' });
});
```

Does anybody know why this difference exists?

Thanks

Comment: How is this working on Mac without opening a connection to the DB first?

Comment: I don't know, but the mongodb website itself contains examples which do it this way:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#insert